# Request membership to Unified Group via Graph

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I have created a web app that utilizes Microsoft Graph to interact with Office 365 Unified Groups. I have implemented functionality to [Add a User to a given Group](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_post_members).

The problem is, this does not let the User request to join the group, it either fails or automatically adds the user without the Group Owner granting access.

Is there any way to do this properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the API you want is available through Microsoft Graph. The only API is the one you've found (you should be using v1.0 rather than beta here though), which requires that the signed-in user is an admin or is an owner of the group (to allow adding another member).

You can request the feature by up-voting an existing request here: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/31672519-provide-api-to-join-leave-office-365-group

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Although not solving the issue as of right now, it did answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

What is the access type of the group. If it is a public group, it will automatically add the user upon request.

Comment: Private groups. That is why we want the option to request made simple.